# oracle and shell scripts

Tags: oracle, shell, unix

I'm using oracle 11g and I'm loading data into the database using the sql loader which are invoked through the unix scripts. I want to select some rows of data and write the data into the file using shell scripts. Is it possible to write a shell script for the same.

Comment: yes, you can using [`sqlplus`](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus)

Comment: a sample shell script here: [Shell script to dump table content into file](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/12/shell-script-how-to-dump-oracle-table-into-csv-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent tutorial which clearly explain how to execute a query from UNIX

Ultimately what he does is login into Oracle i.e., setup a session for Oracle and read a query that needs to be executed and execute that query and do what ever operation needed.

Instead of reading the query from the user we could read it from a file or even hardcode it there itself as per our need.

[Blog which explain about usage of Oracle query in Shell script](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/unix-shell-script-to-execute-oracle-sql-query/)